# jQuery table row divider

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table where the first column value represents a group A, B, C, ... and I'd like to divide each group by giving the last row of each group a border, so in the following example the 2nd and 3rd rows (or the child td elements to be exact) will have a border-bottom style set.

```
<tr><td>A</td><td>4654</td><td>ABAB</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>498</td><td>JOI</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td>165</td><td>FTY</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td>798</td><td>KPO</td></tr>
```

Is there any simple way to do that in jQuery?

EDIT: to make it clear, I include a picture
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>From you question, you want to change the style of each `<td>` on middle `<tr>` tags ie you mentioned, "child td elements". I'll give you a starting point to work on.</del>

```
$('table tr').not(":first").not(":last").find("td:last").css("borderBottom", "1px black solid");
```

<del>Above query first get all the `<tr>`s and the drops the first and last. Then it goes on to select all `<td>`s on `<tr>` that is left. Finally applys the border bottom css.</del>

<del>Please look at Jquery `not` function to deselect first and last from the query.</del>

<del>Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0fhsdfbr/</del>

**Updated:**

There is no built in way to do this as far as I know. You need to write it. Following code go through each `<tr>` tag. If previous  tags first 's content is different than current 's 's content, then it adds a bottom border to child `<td>`s.

```
$('table tr').each(function(index, item){
    //Checks if the contents of previous td differ from current
    if($(item).find("td:first").text() != $(item).prev().find("td:first").text()){
        // If so, underline it
        $(item).prev().find("td").css("borderBottom", "1px black solid");
  }
});
```

Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0fhsdfbr/2/

Comment: no, I want to change the style of the last row of each group. E. g. if there will be rows with 1st column values A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, C, C, D then 3rd, 8th and 10th (doesn't matter if 11th as well) will have the style

Comment: @pedmillon Updated the query. you can check now. https://jsfiddle.net/0fhsdfbr/1/

Comment: If you wants to include the last <td> on last row, remove .not(":last") part

Comment: @pedmillon picture says thousand words.. I think I got it and append new answer to above answer. Cheers ;)

Comment: Your solution works fine, even though I would propose a slight change consisting in adding empty rows instead of simply altering css of last row. Example: [https://jsfiddle.net/0fhsdfbr/4/]. I explained the reasons to do that in the _edit_ section of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't need jquery to do that. Just CSS and tbody / thead tags.

Example:

**Html:**

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>4654</td><td>ABAB</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>498</td><td>JOI</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td><td>165</td><td>FTY</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr><td>C</td><td>798</td><td>KPO</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Css:**

```
thead td,
tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: #000000 solid 1px;
}
td:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: #000000 solid 1px;
}
```

**Jsfiddle:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sst447k/1/)

Css may need to be slightly tweaked if you want continuous borders (changing borders by paddings). [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7sst447k/4/)

And, of course, you can transform existing table using jQuery if you can't change original html or css following the same principle.

**EDIT:** I overlooked the fact you want to group by column value.

In this case make sense to detect them by javascript/jQuery and the easier way to visually achieve it is, as @printfmyname did in his solution, to simply add styles to the last row in each group, avoiding to alter DOM to capture rows and reinject them in several *tbody*s.

...But, anyway, having distinct css for the exact same DOM object types (from the semantic point of view) shocks a little to me.

I mean: It does what question asked for and it does right and in more efficient manner.

...but only if you are sure that you **never** would want to alter that table contents by adding or removing some rows.

If you ever want to do that in the future, you will probably end up messing things too much. For example:

- Removing last row of a group will remove group (visual) separator.
- Adding row (of the same group) after the last row of that group, will (visually) display the row in the next group.

I repeat: I'm not saying that @printfmyname is wrong: It works (which mine doesn't without a little more work). But it can cause some trouble in the future except if we are suere that we will never want to do any dynamic changes to the table.

If we aren't, it could be worth to make a little more effort in semantically grouping rows or, at least, improving @printfmyname solution by inserting empty (and slim) rows with margin to avoid this problem.